# How to pass arguments in function in this case?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am trying to pass an array as an argument to the new php file.

```
$data=array('arr1'=>'haha', 'arr2'=>'wawa');

 function load($view='index',$data=false){

            require $view.'.php';

        if (isset($data)){
            //I want to pass $data(array) to index.php so I can use the array 
            //in index.php page.
            //not sure what to do here.
        }

    }

load('index', $data);
```

index.php

```
<html>
      echo '$arr1 ='.$arr1;
      echo '$arr2 ='.$arr2;
</html>
```

Is this possible? Thanks for any helps.

Comment: You can't really "pass" variables between files per se.  If a variable is defined in the global scope of a file and another file is included, it will be defined in that file's global scope as well (including pretty much just appends the included file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already access that array.

```
 function load($view='index',$data=false){

     require $view.'.php';

 }
```

in your index.php you can do:

```
<p>
   <?=$data['value'];?>
</p>
```

Because you are in the scope of your function.

Please note that are many template engine out there, I strongly suggest you to use one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Before your "require" statement... you could do this:

```
foreach($data as $name => $value) {
    $$name = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused about the actually meaning of including a file. Because including a file pretty much mean that you append the included file, you are not redirecting or something like that. So you will be able to use the variables on your 'view' file If you include it in your file that the variables are defined in.

However You can use php to parse like that, it's great that you keep logic and view separated but I would like to recommend you to try out a template engine, that does all that you try to do but better, in-built escaping, rendering, caching etc.

I would recommend the following engines:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/ Twig, it's great and used in the framework Symfony If i am not mistaken! It's easy to install and use.

An alternative to Twig is Smarty which is also a great template engine and used in many projects out there. http://www.smarty.net/

Have a look at both of them If you wish and decide which one you like the most. But if you are not interested and preferably want your own 'template engine' it's perfectly fine, I am just saying why reinvent the wheel, when there is code that is tested, well written and so forth.

Comment: I do use template engines. Thanks for the help.  +1